# iOS - How to download Audio file

Tags: ios, download

I am currently working on an app which requires me to download audio files from web server. The URL would be something like this: http://universalstreamsolution.com/Samonas/test1.m4a .

Any suggestions on what I should do to be able to reach my goal?

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=download+audio+files+from+web+server&oq=download+audio+files+from+web+server&aqs=chrome..69i57.357j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8#q=download+audio+files+from+web+server+IN+IOS and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749486/sending-an-http-post-request-on-ios/15749527#15749527

Comment: Your title is a bit misleading. I'm not sure what this has to do with HTML at all. So I have amended your tag and title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need the data in the format of data, you can use the data class to download the data with the [method to download the data from an URL](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSData/dataWithContentsOfURL:):

```
[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL]
```

also consider the answer there for playing an NSData as audio: [How to play an audio if we pass NSData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272204/how-to-play-an-audio-if-we-pass-nsdata)

Comment: well, there was really much more to explain. why everything must be a school lesson in developing? sometime, an answer is just an answer

Answer (score 1):

`[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL]` works but it causes UI block so that user can not interact with device till the file is completely downloaded. Such a bad user experience. I suggest using `NSURLSession` with this great tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/51127/nsurlsession-tutorial