# How to upload a sound from my app via a Record Btn to my Parse Class?

Tags: swift, audio, parse-platform, ios5

I'm just a beginner with Parse and I want to know if it's possible 
To record a sounds from my app and then immediately send it to my Parse class and then Play it in my app.

Thank you ...

Comment: You're gonna want to convert the recorded sound into a data type (NSData, url, etc) so you can send that to parse. Then you're going to want to read it from Parse, convert the ParseFile data into readable data to play it in your app. Just a quick rundown of what you got to do, for more info at Parse look through the documentation, it's pretty helpful.

Comment: Also, check this out, it looks like it has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272204/how-to-play-an-audio-if-we-pass-nsdata

Comment: Thank you for your indication.